# How to get rid of the "\n" in my python output

Tags: python, string

```
u'The disclosure relates to systems and methods for detecting features on\n     billets     of laminated veneer lumber (LVL). In some embodiments, an LVL\n     billet is provided and passed through a scanning assembly. The scanning\n     assembly includes anx-raygenerator and anx-raydetector. Thex-raygenerator generates a beam ofx-rayradiation and thex-raydetector\n     measures intensity of the beam ofx-rayradiation after is passes through\n     the LVL billet. The measured intensity is then processed to create an\n     image. Images taken according to the disclosure may then be analyzed todetectfeatures on the LVL billet.'
```

Above is my output.
Now I want to get rid of "\n" in Python.

How can I realize this?
Should I use re module? 
I use `text` to represent all the above text and `text.strip("\n")` have no use at all.
Why?

thank you!

Comment: Changed variable name to `text` because `str` shadows the builtin `str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
''.join(a.split('\n'))
```

a is the output string

Comment: In this case you shouldn't use this, `replace` is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

For a string, `s`, doing:

```
s = s.strip("\n")
```

will only remove the leading and trailing newline characters.

What you want is

```
s = s.replace("\n", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the replace function?

```
s = u'The disclosure relates to systems and methods for detecting features on\n     billets     of laminated veneer lumber (LVL). In some embodiments, an LVL\n     billet is provided and passed through a scanning assembly. The scanning\n     assembly includes anx-raygenerator and anx-raydetector. Thex-raygenerator generates a beam ofx-rayradiation and thex-raydetector\n     measures intensity of the beam ofx-rayradiation after is passes through\n     the LVL billet. The measured intensity is then processed to create an\n     image. Images taken according to the disclosure may then be analyzed todetectfeatures on the LVL billet.'

s.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: bingo! I got it. Yeah, that's useful.Sorry I'm a greenhand. thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice one! Also a greenhand, finding SO incredibly addictive

Answer (score -1):

```
str = 'The disclosure relates to systems and methods for detecting features on\n     billets     of laminated veneer lumber (LVL).'
str.replace('\n', '')
' '.join(str.split())
```

Output

```
The disclosure relates to systems and methods for detecting features on billets of laminated veneer lumber (LVL).
```

Comment: yeah.thas's the best output form